# How many debug options can I set while building OpenJDK on Linux?

Tags: build, jvm, java

I want to build a debug version openJDK on my own PC, does anybody can tell me all the debug options while building the openJDK.

So far, i know:

```
DEBUG_NAME=all_fastdebug
BUILD_JAXWS=false
BUILD_JAXP=false
```

Anything else? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at the [Makefile](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/file/ee67ee3bd597/Makefile) for openjdk7 and see all of the options.

Only `DEBUG_NAME` is related to debug, the rest are just for selecting which components to build

This is what I found in the makefile:

```
DEBUG_NAME=fastdebug
BUILD_HOTSPOT=false
BUILD_JDK=false
BUILD_LANGTOOLS=false
BUILD_CORBA=false
BUILD_JAXP=false
BUILD_JAXWS=false
UILD_INSTALL=false
BUILD_SPONSORS=false
```

Comment: Thanks! As makefile says, `DEBUG_NAME` is fastdebug or debug. Is there a diference between `fastdebug` and `debug`

Comment: `fastdebug` is built with less compiler optimizations so it builds a little faster

Comment: Yeah, but is there a details list?

Comment: debug is with `-g`, fastdebug with `-g -O`: `fastdebug_build   -- build the core JDK in 'fastdebug' mode (-g -O)`
`debug_build       -- build the core JDK in 'debug' mode (-g)`